# Backbone - Collection fetch returns undefined?

Tags: backbone.js

I have an application using backbone but whenever I call the `fetch()` method for the collection it returns undefined:

```
// App

(function () {

    window.app = {};
    app.collections = {};
    app.models = {};
    app.views = {};

    $(function () {
        app.collections.complaintTypes = new app.collections.ComplaintTypesCollection();
        app.views.complaintTypesView = new app.views.ComplaintTypesView({ collection: app.collections.complaintTypes });
    });

})();

// Collections

(function (collections, model) {
    collections.ComplaintTypesCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        initialize: function () {
            this.fetch();
        },
        model: model,
        url: '/api/ComplaintTypes'
    });
})(app.collections, app.models.ComplaintType);

// Models

(function (models) {
    models.ComplaintType = Backbone.Model.extend({
        idAttribute: 'ComplaintTypeId'
    });
})(app.models);


// Views

(function (views) {
    views.ComplaintTypesView = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function () {
            this.collection.on('reset', this.render, this);
        },
        render: function () {
            console.log(this.collection);
        }
    });
})(app.views);
```

But this doesn't return anything? If I use fiddler and go to my URL: /api/ComplaintTypes I do retrieve data back so I'm not sure what Im doing wrong here?

Comment: Which is the exactly error message? which is the exactly line of your code that produces the error?

Comment: The error is: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` and the line of code is in Backbone.js, line: 815

Comment: Use your javascript console to check the _backtrace_ of the error and find the first line of your code that is in the list.

Comment: My code doesnt appear, its either backbone.js or jquery..

Comment: This is very un-usual :/, can you plis paste the _error backtrace_ somewhere and share a link?

Comment: I found the problem I had my model definition after my collection definition, I moved my model above and it works now

Comment: I'm glad you found your issue, I recommend to remove the question due it was related to a very personal typo.

Answer (score 3):

Deleting "model" line in the collection file worked for me.

Comment: Brothers, deleting the line is not the solution. It just aggravates the situation. The problem here is, the "collection" function is executed even before "models" function is encountered. As a result, the model "model" is not available at the time of execution. Write the Model function before Collection function. This helped me.

Answer (score 1):

Fetch is async. If you need to get the results, you need to pass a "success" handler, i.e.:

```
function myHandler(models) {

}
...
this.fetch({success: myHandler});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you create the view while the collection has not been fetched yet (because of JS's asynchronous behavior). Try this way:

```
$(function () {
    app.collections.complaintTypes = new app.collections.ComplaintTypesCollection();
    app.collections.complaintTypes.fetch({success:function(){
        app.views.complaintTypesView = new app.views.ComplaintTypesView({ collection: app.collections.complaintTypes });
    }});      
});
```

And remove the initialize function from your collection.

Comment: I've just tried this but I still get the same error. I even put a console.log inside the success function but it output anything

Comment: Well so you get some error from the fetch method... try to add a error callback after the success callback to confirm that: `error: function(){console.log("there is a error!");}`

Comment: So I think that the error came from your new collection call. Did you remove the initialize function from your collection definition?

Comment: Yes, it just contains model and url now.

Comment: I'm not familiar with your code style but I think that the problem may reside in how you reference 'model' in your collection function, because line 815 of backbone.js refers to a new model function: `model = new this.model(attrs, options);`

Comment: Figured it out, as you see I have my Collection definition BEFORE my model definition so you're right, it can't find my model..